# What is twitter's Future.trace() method used for?

Tags: java, scala, twitter, trace, finagle

The class `com.twitter.util.Future` has a method `Future.trace()`, return type is `com.twitter.util.Future.Tracer` (this can be found in the compiled Java class)

However, I couldn't find that method in the original [Scala code](https://github.com/twitter/util/blob/master/util-core/src/main/scala/com/twitter/util/Future.scala) or in the [doc](http://twitter.github.com/util/util-core/target/doc/main/api/com/twitter/util/package.html). Do you know where I can find the usage or source code for that method?

Why I'm doing this: I'm trying to implement my own tracing framework using Finagle trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Future.trace` is actually an old member of the `Future` object. It was used to enable registration of call stack every time you link two asynchronous computations together with `map/flatMap`. This feature wasn't very popular, so we just remove it.

If you want to look at a tracing Framework you should look at [zipkin](http://github.com/twitter/zipkin), and [finagle-zipkin](https://github.com/twitter/finagle/tree/master/finagle-zipkin) that's basically an open-source implementation of Google's Dapper (See [paper](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en/us/pubs/archive/36356.pdf))

Answer (score 0):

It is a version problem.

The Java code package has the following signature

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
  <artifactId>util-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

but the document and the source code are > 6.0.5

There seems to have been a radical change in the source code between the versions.